# ProgressDialog in an AsyncTask, NullPointerException

Tags: android

I've managed to implement an Asynctask for calculating something, but I also want to show a progress dialog while doInBackground runs.

This is my code so far:

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    this.dialog.show(); 

    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... b) {

            ........

     return price;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer price) {

    if(dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    Toast.makeText(_ctx, price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

When I run the debugger it says that the dialog just contains `NULL`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate your `dialog` (e.g. `dialog = new ProgressDialog(_ctx)`);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this` try `getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'this.dailog' in onPreExecute() with your 'ActivityClassname.this'. Because the dialogbox is on your activity context but here 'this' refers to your class that extends AsyncTask class.

Comment: Then I need to declare the ProgressDialog in my Main Activity?

Comment: ya... here you need to declare it in main activity. Only the thing is while you are instantiating the progress bar just pass yuor main activity context as the parameter to it. Some what like this,  dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);